# How can I get a column value from selected database object in ListBox?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq, linq-to-sql

First, I must say that I am new to LINQ and WPF.

I have a 'Students' table in database that contains information about students (name, id, etc.).
I want to get an information about a student that was selected in the ListBox on MainForm.

```
var students = from s in db.Students select s;
listBox.DisplayMemberPath = "name"; 
listBox.ItemsSource = students;
```

I put all the information about students into `var student`. I want only the `name` of the student to be shown in the ListBox. Is there any way to get a value of `id` column from `var students` without query to database?
I mean something like that:

```
var id = listBox.SelectedItem.getValue("id");
```

Comment: var id = (Student)listBox.SelectedItem.Id;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution and the reason why my code didn't work the way I wanted.

First, the solution is very simple:

Just define a source:

```
var students = from s in db.Students select s;
StudentsListBox.ItemsSource = students;
```

And now I can just make a simple cast and retrieve the information:

```
var id = ((Student)StudentsList.SelectedItem).id_student;
```

This cast did't work before, because I binded the listBox only to one column:

```
var students = from s in db.Students select s.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to retrieve data from the student table.
I want to get an information about a student that was selected in the ListBox.
so i hope below code will helpful to you.

**Code**

```
var students = from s in db.Students select s;
listBox.DataTextField ="name"; 
listBox.DataValueField = "student_id";
listBox.DataSource = students;
listBox.DataBind();
```

i hope it will help you.

Comment: That's not actually working for me. I'll post the solution, if I'll find it.